# Photoshop CS5 is not importing full gif

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I have this image

[image]

But I need to edit part of it, the problem is that photoshop is not importing half of the frames.

I mean, when I import the image into the animation bar, it show only the first 4 seconds of animation, the part when "FAST MIGRATION" text appear **is not showing at all**, instead I keep seeing a snapshot of the last frame before that one, until the whole animation resets. Here's an example:

[image]

Here's what happening:

### http://youtu.be/GUfNUxVM7V0?hd=1

---

Any idea how to solve this?? It's pretty weird, I can't realize what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is. Opening your top GIF with Photoshop CC2014 suffers from the same stop half way through.

However, I was able to access all frames by:

- Opening your top gif with Fireworks CS6
- Export as animated GIF
- Open *that* new animated GIF with Photoshop CC2014

*Then*, and only then, were all frames present in Photoshop.

Here's the gif after export from Fireworks:

[image]

Comment: Since I don't have Fireworks installed, can you please share with me the image you've exported from that software? Maybe this "first image" is somehow "corrupted" or something like that :S

Comment: You might not need Fireworks. I'd try any app, other than Photoshop, that can open and save an animated GIF.